# Aggregate trunc date function?

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, truncate

I worked with a bunch of SQL databases before; like Postgres and BigQuery and they have date truncation function (for instance: [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) or [`TIMESTAMP_TRUNC`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_trunc) ).

I wonder if mongodb has a DATE_TRUNC function?

I have found the [`$trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/) operator but it works for numbers only.

I want a DATE_TRUNC function to truncate a given Date (the timestamp type in other SQL databases) to a particular boundary, like beginning of year, beginning of month, beginning of hour, may be ok to compose a new Date by getting its year, month, date, hour.

Does someone have some kinds of workaround? Especially for beginning moment of WEEK, and beginning of ISOWEEK, does anyone have a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to get the start of ISO week by doing arithmetic on date or timestamp field, here the start of week is `Monday` (1)  and end of week is `Sunday` (7)

```
db.dd.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $addFields : { 
                startOfWeek : 1, // Monday
                currentDayOfWeek : {$dayOfWeek : "$date"}, 
                daysToMinus : { $subtract : [{$dayOfWeek : "$date"} , 1] },
                startOfThisWeek : { $subtract : [ "$date", {$multiply : [{ $subtract : [{$dayOfWeek : "$date"} , 1 ] }, 24, 60, 60, 1000 ]  } ] }
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

document

```
> db.dd.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a62e2697702c6be61d672f4"), "date" : ISODate("2018-01-20T06:32:09.157Z") }
```

start of week

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a62e2697702c6be61d672f4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-01-20T06:32:09.157Z"),
    "startOfWeek" : 1,
    "currentDayOfWeek" : 7,
    "daysToMinus" : 6,
    "startOfThisWeek" : ISODate("2018-01-14T06:32:09.157Z")
}
>
```

Comment: this may be the most simple answer with existing mongodb; also complex enough~    wonder if such date_trunc is in popular need, someone can request a feature and possibly implemented in future versions?

Comment: OP asked for DateTrunc to beginning of the week should have a result like ISODate("2018-01-14T00:00:00.000Z"); it's definitely doable by your approach, just would be more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Can be combined [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) and [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/)

For **year**, **month**, **day**, **hour**, **minute**:

```
db.getCollection("data").aggregate([
  {"$addFields": {
     "dateVarFull": {"$dateToParts": {date: {"$toDate" : "2020-08-27T13:00:00Z"}}}
  }},
  {"$addFields": {
    "dateVarTrunc": { "$dateFromParts": {
      'year': "$dateVarFull.year",
      'month': "$dateVarFull.month",
      'day': "$dateVarFull.day"
    }}
  }}
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "dateVarFull" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2020), 
        "month" : NumberInt(8), 
        "day" : NumberInt(27), 
        "hour" : NumberInt(13), 
        "minute" : NumberInt(0), 
        "second" : NumberInt(0), 
        "millisecond" : NumberInt(0)
    }, 
    "dateVarTrunc" : ISODate("2020-08-27T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

For **week** trunc use `iso8601: true` parameter:

```
db.getCollection("data").aggregate([
  {"$addFields": {
    "dateVarFull": {
       "$dateToParts": {
         date: {"$toDate" : "2020-08-27T13:00:00Z"},
         iso8601: true
       }
    }
  }},
  {"$addFields": {
    "dateVarTrunc": { "$dateFromParts": {
      'isoWeekYear': "$dateVarFull.isoWeekYear",
      'isoWeek': "$dateVarFull.isoWeek",
      'isoDayOfWeek': 1
    }}
  }}
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "dateVarFull" : {
        "isoWeekYear" : NumberInt(2020), 
        "isoWeek" : NumberInt(35), 
        "isoDayOfWeek" : NumberInt(4), 
        "hour" : NumberInt(13), 
        "minute" : NumberInt(0), 
        "second" : NumberInt(0), 
        "millisecond" : NumberInt(0)
    }, 
    "dateVarTrunc" : ISODate("2020-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to truncate date to iso week with [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) function:

For example

```
db.dd.aggregate(
  {
    $dateFromParts: {
      isoWeekYear: { $isoWeekYear: "$date" },
      isoWeek: { $isoWeek: "$date" }
    }
  }
)
```

For `Fri, 22 Jun 2018 20:46:50 UTC +00:00` it returns `Fri, 18 Jun 2018 00:00:00 UTC +00:00`.

To truncate to hour, day, month, etc. it's easier to use `$dateFromString` and `$dateToString`. The following example truncated date to hour:

```
db.dd.aggregate(
  {
    $dateFromString: {
      dateString: { 
        $dateToString: {
          format: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00+00:00',
          date: '$date'
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, your wish has been granted with the [`$dateTrunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) operator.

For instance, to truncate dates to their year:

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-05T13:20:56Z") }
// { date: ISODate("2019-04-27T05:00:32Z") }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { year: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: "year" } } } }
])
// { year: ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
// { year: ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

You can truncate at different levels of units (year, months, day, hours, ... even quarters) using the `unit` parameter. And for a given unit at different multiples of units (for instance 3 years, 6 months, ...) using the `binSize` parameter.

And you can also specify the day at which weeks start:

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-05T13:20:56Z") } <= Sunday
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-06T05:00:32Z") } <= Monday
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    week: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: "week", startOfWeek: "monday" } }
  }}
])
// { week: ISODate("2021-11-29T00:00:00Z") }
// { week: ISODate("2021-12-06T00:00:00Z") }
```