# How to update collection 'Date' values to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: mongodb

I have some DATE values in a MESSAGES collection such as the following:

```
{ "Date" : "15-07-2014 11:48:14" }
{ "Date" : "15-07-2014 11:48:14" }
{ "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:44" }
{ "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:44" }
{ "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:49" }
{ "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:49" }
```

How can the collection be altered so the Date values are represented as YYYY-MM-DD?

I've been looking at the function $dateFromString but this looks like it's applied to queries and not sure this can be permanently applied to the collection.

Comment: Maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351590/mongodb-aggregate-trunc-date-function

Answer (score 0):

We can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to replace data of specified collection with the aggregation output. The following query would permanently update `messages` collection.

```
db.messages.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "Date":{
                $dateToString:{
                    "date":{
                        $toDate:"$Date"
                    },
                    "format":"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out:"messages"
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Before:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09ef"),
    "Date" : "15-07-2014 11:48:14"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f0"),
    "Date" : "15-07-2014 11:48:14"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f1"),
    "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:44"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f2"),
    "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:44"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f3"),
    "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:49"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f4"),
    "Date" : "16-07-2014 13:37:49"
}
```

**After:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09ef"),
    "Date" : "2014-07-15 11:48:14"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f0"),
    "Date" : "2014-07-15 11:48:14"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f1"),
    "Date" : "2014-07-16 13:37:44"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f2"),
    "Date" : "2014-07-16 13:37:44"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f3"),
    "Date" : "2014-07-16 13:37:49"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d728d92eb1b7fdde7ea09f4"),
    "Date" : "2014-07-16 13:37:49"
}
```